# Attempting to Set Text of SPAN element on asp.net page from JavaScript using JQuery

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I am attempting to set text in a SPAN element from JavaScript and it is not working.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The HTML on the asp.net page is as follows:

```
<div class="TimerRowDetail TimerDaysDetail">
   <asp:Label ID="lblDays" runat="server"  Text="yyy" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>            
</div>
```

The generated HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="TimerRowDetail TimerDaysDetail">
     <span id="lblDays">yyy</span>            
 </div>
```

My JavaScript is as follows:

```
var lblDays = $("#<%=lblDays.ClientID%>");
if (lblDays != null)
{
   alert("OK");
   lblDays.innerHTML = "XXX";
}
```

I see the OK alert but the text never changes to XXX.

I am testing with both IE 9 and FireFox 9.0.1.

Thanks.
**EDIT:**

Ok, I am not suggesting the answer icarus gave is incorrect, only that it is not working in my environment.

Below is the source for the page including the script I am using.  It does not work on my machine.

```
<%@ Page 
    Language="C#" 
    AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="DatePlay.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="CountDownClock.WebUI.DatePlay" 
%>

<!DOCTYPE html >

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var lblDays = $("#<%=lblDays.ClientID%>");
        lblDays.html("XXX");
        alert("done");
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="lblDays" runat="server"  Text="yyy" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Again I am using IE 9 and FireFox on a Windows 7 box with HTML5 specified in the

Any suggestions would really be appreciated.

Comment: Have you wrapped the script in $(document).ready(...) or included it after the tag are present in the DOM?

Comment: If you're using `ClientIDMode="Static"`, then why are you using `$("#<%=lblDays.ClientID%>")` and not just `$("#lblDays")`?

Comment: @ShaneBlake it makes no difference but I think Anthony's practice is better in case the ClientIDMode ever changes for whatever reason.

Comment: @Icarus - This makes the `ClientIDMode` seting less than useless...  Use it, or don't use it, but don't clutter up the code.

Comment: @ShaneBlake it's not cluttering; it's covering your ass. You don't lose readability.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$(document).ready()` to run your code once the DOM has loaded and the element can be accessed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var lblDays = $('#<%=lblDays.ClientID%>');
      lblDays.html("XXX");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var lblDays = $("#<%=lblDays.ClientID%>");
  if (lblDays != null)
  {

    lblDays.html("XXX");
 }
}
```

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez No, I am afraid you are wrong. I just tested it. I hope next time you take the time to TEST before downvoting unless you are 100% confident of your answer.

Comment: ok, it works. sorry for that. But you have to agree that the if statement isn't doing nothing, becaus lnlDays is never going to be null

Comment: Icarus, please see my EDIT of the question.  It does not work for me.  Not sure why.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @AnthonyNelms Because you are doing `lblDays.html = "XXX";` and it should be `lblDays.html ("XXX");` See the difference?

Comment: I edited my edit to show the change I made from lblDays.html = "XXX" to lblDays.html("XXX");  Again for me it is not working.  I know this is simple but I cannot see my mistakes on this problem.

Comment: @AnthonyNelms I saw your edit. If that's all your code, obviously will never work because you are not calling your function. See my answer. I added a piece of code that you are missing.

Comment: I see now....the script was running at script load time and it WAS modifying the text, but the Label (span) was loaded after the fact.  The script was not encloised in a function so it was excuting early on.  I changed it to be enclosed in a script and then called the script before the LABEL on the page and it "failed" to set the ext to XXX.  I move the calling script on the page to appear AFTER the label and it set the text to XXX after the label had loaded.  The XXX was then visible.

I tried to VOTE UP your answer, but my reputation is too low....sorry...but thanks for the great help...

Answer (score 0):

jQUery selector returns an HTML list, not an element, even if it only selects 1 element.

So:

```
$(lblDays).html('XXX')
```

or

```
lblDays[0].innerHTML = 'XXX'
```

Also, when the script is being executed, the label doesn't exist in the DOM yet. you should wrap it with

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

or move the script to the end of the body.